# Spring MVC - doesn't see expected output at localhost:8080

Tags: java, apache, maven, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC, and I was running the code I was supposed to run from https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch

When I ran in the command `curl localhost:8080` on `cmd` I got the expected output - Greetings from Spring Boot! **The right output**.

I was running **maven** with Intelij, but this happened also when I used eclipse.

However, when logged into the broswer, I got this symbol of appache server instead of the expected output-

[image]

These has happend to me several times when running maven on port 8080. In the broswer this appache icon apperaed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which URL do you enter in the browser?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: @SvenHakvoort ok this is pretty silly but I found it. The problem was indeed the URL - needed to make it - http://localhost:8080// instead of one /. Thank you!